# Accessing index of nested list passing single item in the index() method

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, data-structures, nested-lists

I have a nested list

```
points = [[26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

so if I want to access any of the list index, I can use index() method

```
points.index([26, 27, 28, 29, 30])
```

This will give me the index of the list which is 0 in this case.

Is there any other way to access the index using single item of nested list? like below:

```
points.index(30)
```

so it will give me the index of nested list which contains the point 30

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the method? Is there a trying about n steps lists in there?

Comment: Yeah I've read the documentation. It does not offer such operation. But Is there any other way equivalent to my approach? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own function that will mimic the `.index()` method. For example:

```
def my_index(lst, n):
    for i, l in enumerate(lst):
        if n in l:
            return i
    raise ValueError("{} not found".format(n))


print(my_index(points, 30))
```

Prints:

```
0
```

Or throws `ValueError` if `n` is not found (just as `.index()`)